# JS image on click

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, createjs

I have made a startscreen with an playbutton image on it. When this button is pushed, the init function should be launched. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Below the code:

```
imgPlaybutton.onload = handleImageLoad;

imgPlaybutton.src = "img/play.png";
playbutton = new createjs.Bitmap(imgPlaybutton);
playbutton.x = 410;
playbutton.y = 190;
stage.addChild(playbutton);
playbutton.onclick = init;
```

Comment: what about `imgPlaybutton.onclick=init`?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html#method_addEventListener

```
playbutton.addEventListener('click', init);
```

Previously, you could use

```
// Note the capital C in onClick
playbutton.onClick = init;
```

but that is deprecated

Side note: Please use `var` in your code

Comment: There is an even easier API in the latest version. Check out http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html#method_on